# VSTS API REST Doesn't download sources correctly

Tags: rest, api, powershell, azure-devops

After try to search for a solution of my problem I found some fixes that can be aplyied locally using tf.exe but I cannot found a fix for VSTS Task.

That's my problem:

After create a build in VSTS I launched and it seems to run correctly. Same for other builds.
Now I'm trying to trigger multiple builds from one master build definition. All triggered from a Powershell script.
I found in internet a script that achive this, only I need is to use VSTS REST API and an url like this:

```
"$($env:SYSTEM_TEAMFOUNDATIONCOLLECTIONURI)$env:SYSTEM_TEAMPROJECTID/_apis/build/builds?api-version=2.0"
```

Even I can send params using Json like this:

```
"{ 'definition' : { 'id' : $sBuildId }, 'sourceBranch' : '$env:BUILD_SOURCEBRANCH', 'parameters' : ""{ 'buildMasterNumber' : '$sBuildMasterNumber', 'BranchName' : '$sBranchName' }"" }"
```

The problem I'm facing is when I queue a build via external build it never download  the sources, the output says:

```
2018-03-01T12:48:14.6043553Z ##[command]tf vc get /version:7809 /recursive /overwrite E:\agent\_work\194\s /loginType:OAuth /login:.,******** /noprompt
2018-03-01T12:48:24.1992120Z All files are up to date.
2018-03-01T12:48:24.2773348Z ##[section]Finishing: Get Sources
```

As you can see always is showing message "All files are up to date" and next task is NuGet restore which never can find *.sln files.

But everything seems to work fine if I trigger the build directly without use REST API.

Note: *$env:BUILD_SOURCEBRANCH* is diferent in both build definitions but even if I found correct sourcebranch value it never runs correctly or without this value in Json params.

Can anyone help me with that?

Thanks a lot, I will apreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That’s because you queue a new for the same TFVC repo by using `$env:BUILD_SOURCEBRANCH` in REST API, which value is the TFVC repo when you execute the PowerShell task.

Assume you execute the PowerShell task (queue a new build) in buildA (build for `$/project1` TFVC repo), and you want to queue a new build for `$/project2`.

Since the PowerShell task is executing in BuildA for `$/project1`, when you use the predefined variable `$env:BUILD_SOURCEBRANCH`, and value is `$/project1`.

If you want to queue a new build for a different repo `$/project2`, you should specify `$/project2` in the build definition and skip to specify `sourceBranch` in PowerShell task (or you can use string `$/project2` to replace `$env:BUILD_SOURCEBRANCH` in the REST API):

[image]

The application/json for the REST API to queue a new build should be:

```
"{ 'definition' : { 'id' : $sBuildId }, 'parameters' : ""{ 'buildMasterNumber' : '$sBuildMasterNumber', 'BranchName' : '$sBranchName' }"" }"
```

**Note:** Since you also use the predefined variable `$env:SYSTEM_TEAMPROJECTID` in your first build, if the new queued build definition located in a different project, you should use the project name/id instead.

Comment: I reviewed all params in script and in all builds are some differences. Adding new parameters into script solve my problem. Thanks a lot Marina.